# vega-lite change color scale of selected bars

Tags: vega-lite

I'm trying to make the selected bars follow a different color scale, as shown below
[image]

Using this code

```
"color": {
      "condition": {
          "test": {
            "and": [{"selection": "select"}, "length(data(\"select_store\"))"]
          },
          "field": "is_overview",
          "type": "nominal",
          "scale": {"range": ["red", "yellow"], "domain": [false, true]},
          "legend": null
        },
        "field": "is_overview",
        "type": "nominal",
        "scale": {"range": ["blue", "#9FB3C8"], "domain": [false, true]},
        "legend": null
    },
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything.

Here is the [link to full code on vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-f97SA8DC2YZA3CEOg8DMIFYqSn4MrtAADHQG7+SlujcPpVLklKkumITp5S6T0h6g2kDy3kSvIAA6pYLDVRKzJKCVxiciD4o1asOjXo7NVQHVnKNSN1R261Pt1h17MONQvX9UNbV4GNeATdNs1ae7oMg40atUn6IMaVMXxduL+PS7imcCniQA).

Thanks for the help!

Edit: I was able to resolve the original question based on Jake's answer, however, I ran into another issue for a variant of the code---as show [here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATZAgBOjQnh4qckALKNN6WGADiyJcl3o8yTWABqjWK3QSAXi7GYNwAZmBWeOihzqjIYABiAJIASgCiAPoAykkAWpma3nj67KxGymoakLDIYsjw5SZgoBAQkP7c3KjYzRqtUHgAnoTIPZCMSq66FH6V-W3sE5pjCH46c-OQxehKsGIuo6YA2qjcrDWa3ADuSkcAhMhUk3SwiIyheADSyIMAuqpgK5La5YU7nZCsQi-MAAPkBwKuoLONVOVDuG367U63VMVxQtXRfTAAF91Jj2Lpzogei1NkMRmMJlMZmIMa1ILodNwxFQxqwlMY2W0KscwRdrrdHg48C83h9vn8AUClJdEWKIVDYfCVSD1ajkOiyXTnLt9q4xidkW4JUcpc9Xu8vj9-trVUjwZDoXDlW69dw0UKoB0uj0lKwxGIjZiHPBuIUlNRYGMAB6QInEjSkqqRTA4WltFmsdY4I5EiDASDJdLZPKZRZNAAMAMgsf5eB6AEYAJzN7wZf1OCiMZBXHrFItZ+bNSupTI5fIZes9ADMDbXzdbkx6AA5e7B+1RpsPRzhx8hJ-MK1W57XFxMegA2NdNqCb9s4ACse4Pg+PY8p55Rq0V6zjWC5LjgXbPhuZxbjgABM34DkeI7-hOQHljO1bznW944B28HQa+sHvmAiFQH2yFDqhp4ARe-Qgdht4QWAHYfkRLYkZ2L7jPuVF-rR6FltO15gbhTTwR2HFvj0X4UXxh7USeYBnvRwFYTe4F4WRUnrsRbadkhikCWAoR+DUamYaJOF3k0bHSVx+FGb+NGmeZgHCYxmniZ2hF6ZxBlOfJP4ocpZliBZRK-JmRqQBgugANZjOw6C6BskAxnGEzUDSRKQKmeaQKEw5iMspjWcx97NvShxQAAjr4kzMEEvJqZAgw0kVJVlfpW7VcMtWQA1OxGFERi8s2sBRPASU4GGEZtdwhDoPAzAdYVha1Q2dAfhmEAXpA+yDE4PSlgxwlxals1QClaUYVAmXxjlebCW0sZiNwaUvVOmLFbUPW8SFSmBpiNVjEoXQTLM92YqsdSdSa1C1UckAAMRrsuaQPgAQmoUCo12CTY8uADC26QC6kCXBg2lHOFNQAmevyWZsdRIyqobhmIr0ksJLPVLU9SNLlP1QDUdQNJ1YOmKg4ZGHjGVKLGT1JiW+UU82aCGOtUAQ44kB7fMhv7UB+bsvF12QLdgZbCasChJ9OJgEcFbFWIUydeLQuCqYFJUgbxL-Bdj3ZSLP2cR9X29KLbR-aVjIKS5o4w+y0u65DSjQzzbRw7VFaI8jaOhJo26aMu8AK6jxfoMgD7sBrWhdOgtP08gjMAczKdtGzDg9fN3Oi8brRD4bQdtJyig8nn1TwGsnXvZ9jIqsgIzL1uxIZsSQA)---it's basically the same idea but using a brush---would really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to have two different encodings for a single channel: channel conditions can only switch between an encoding and a static value, or between two static values.

A way to get the behavior you want is to use a layered chart with a filter transform to overlay the alternate encoding. Here is an example ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATZAgBOjQnh4qckALKNN6WGADiyJcl3o8yTWABqjWK3QSAXi7GYNwAZmBWeOihzqjIYADKACoAgkkAogD6mt54+uysRspqGpCRmDigEBCQFH6sOthgANoa1WDAkMlp6U2QKQDSalDw3KxKeE0ATKpQ3pncVLoUjMgA7k15DQC+6u0Qnd0ZfSkAMsOQo+OTOACMAOwAzLOQ84tOK+ubujt7+4epY6mFIAJQuVwmTQAbM85rAFktPhscFtkLs2tUAT0TgAtcFjSF3ACcsNe8Pey1WyLAqPR+w6XUBvVMAGEUvjrk1Hk8Xm9EVTvr8MQdGdjWQB5DmEsC3ACsMzhCI+ApRPzRf3aWKBUAAYucXhCbjLHkTeeT+V9VUL6VrmVBBlKjbczUrKZawKE-LB1cKGUc7f19SMCUaeYqKUimp6xN66f9Rdr+mCDSHpqS+cr3dHYxrMQmAyk8SnOTgSS6IyqPV6fTb8302Y6mmGya7IzhszX4-765Li9L5eWLdSO3HNXXTHrGzgTYPM8Pq9sMQBdDRxyAOUY5JTUJpVaqQAAeu8goVWYk0fW7LzwAE9CMg+txdFu-JBR1Ab8fT8hz31DRdb3vPoAEdfAmZggioC5YCieAAGsmiUVgxDEd9IG4Qh0HgZhP0qWp6gfHAAAY6FlNCYN0bg4MIhk6jEBo+gAYh1IiACFpCmIk31XP5IDEdAbycJpWk1X1IAwXQENMdh0F0Ep6XXJRN0Ybdd19GpRjEJ81PpdoTzPC9TAzN0NlzBTAJoyAlG4VAVNfMz9kgBA-BozpnG3Gjmkgdh6IfF5GKJHVWMeFkAA5ICXF5NBs9AVOEjtZlRJd3wUsQaAcQywCQlD1LAFL9woqjkAAdUsFhjzohjiMXel8qcn9kHgIoTA6XL6rSprjwsvpUGQowLg3bgt2oWBhMPCKXjQQxcKgazHG42qMXfPc9IkqSoBkuSHMgPJ0CUWBQifVBhM6U8xFcOS8O9Drmr6a7GsmbZtkisTBuGnTdMubgtMu1rdP3b9fyM8053k-6oG60xrNspR7NympnLS493OoTzIF0NwLkElDuA2SKtBiuKcGaBKaTVZKHL0tLUaUTLsrEXL8oRvIitKzRyrwyqaMeGr9l5iBeZemoMcUMQoKu+AXOPTTtKM2nkHveXISekBtiAA)):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "Midas Generated Visualization of dataframe STATE_distribution",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"STATE": "AK", "count": 2, "is_overview": true},
      {"STATE": "AL", "count": 173, "is_overview": true},
      {"STATE": "AR", "count": 63, "is_overview": true},
      {"STATE": "AZ", "count": 193, "is_overview": true},
      {"STATE": "CA", "count": 373, "is_overview": true},
      {"STATE": "CO", "count": 152, "is_overview": true},
      {"STATE": "FL", "count": 139, "is_overview": true},
      {"STATE": "AK", "count": 1, "is_overview": false},
      {"STATE": "AL", "count": 73, "is_overview": false},
      {"STATE": "AR", "count": 23, "is_overview": false},
      {"STATE": "AZ", "count": 93, "is_overview": false},
      {"STATE": "CA", "count": 73, "is_overview": false},
      {"STATE": "CO", "count": 52, "is_overview": false},
      {"STATE": "FL", "count": 39, "is_overview": false}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "STATE", "type": "ordinal"},
    "y": {"field": "count", "type": "quantitative", "stack": null},
    "opacity": {"value": 0.5},
    "stroke": {"value": "#F0B429"}
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "field": "is_overview",
          "type": "nominal",
          "scale": {"range": ["blue", "#9FB3C8"], "domain": [false, true]},
          "legend": null
        },
        "strokeWidth": {"value": 0}
      },
      "selection": {
        "select": {"type": "multi", "encodings": ["x"], "empty": "none"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "transform": [{"filter": {"selection": "select"}}],
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "field": "is_overview",
          "type": "nominal",
          "scale": {"range": ["red", "yellow"], "domain": [false, true]},
          "legend": null
        },
        "strokeWidth": {"value": 3}
      }
    }
  ],
  "resolve": {"scale": {"color": "independent"}}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jake for the help! I added another question variant to the original question (with the full code in the link) -- would you mind following up on that briefly? Thanks so much.

Comment: Your schema is invalid because a layer chart cannot have ``"selection"`` or ``"mark"`` specified at the top level. You can see these fields highlighted as invalid in the vega editor.